# Encode json data with two tables

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with my code. I have two tables which are sales and expense. I can't JSON encode the data from the first table, it always returns the data from the expense table. How can I encode the data from the sales table? Thanks!

This what I've tried:

```
public function sales_expense_chart() {
    $sales_query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(payment_amount) as total_sales FROM tbl_sales_payments");
    $result = $sales_query->fetch_object();
    $expense_query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(expense_total - expense_vat) as total_expenses FROM tbl_expense_transactions WHERE expense_remarks = 'RELEASED'");
    $result = $expense_query->fetch_object();

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Result:
[image: response]

Comment: Maybe don't use the same variable for two different things...

Comment: `JOIN` your SQL query so you only do one query while getting the data from both table at the same time